# Wer ist der "wahre Jacob"?

Tags: phrase, idiom

In einem Brief an Max Born, einen der Gründer der Quantenmechanik, schreibt 1926 Einstein (dem diese Theorie nicht gefiel, obwohl er auch einer deren Gründer war):

> Die Quantenmechanik ist sehr Achtung gebietend. Aber eine innere
>   Stimme sagt mir, dass das noch nicht der wahre Jakob ist.

Dank dem Zusammenhang verstehe ich, was Einstein meint, aber ich möchte wissen, woher der Ausdruck *wahrer Jacob*  kommt und ob er damals (oder jetzt) üblich ist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Hier](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~etwas%20ist%20nicht%20der%20wahre%20Jakob&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5b%5d=rart_ou) ist eine detaillierte Beschreibung. Anbei das Wichtigste:

> Jakobus, der Bruder des Johannes, war einer der zwölf Apostel Jesu. Die beiden Brüder und Petrus galten als engste Vertraute Jesu (Bibel, Mark. 5,37ff). König Herodes ließ den Jakobus 44 n. Chr. enthaupten (Apg. 12,2). Seit dem 7. Jahrhundert gibt es die (wahrscheinlich unhistorische) Legende, dass Jakobus in Spanien gewirkt haben soll. Sein angebliches Grab wurde der Ursprung der Stadt Santiago de Compostela in Nordspanien. Als nationaler Schutzheiliger Spaniens genoss Jakobus insbesondere im Mittelalter höchste Verehrung, so dass Santiago neben Jerusalem zum bedeutendsten Wallfahrtsort der Christenheit wurde. **Nur in Santiago de Compostela liegt "der wahre Jakob" begraben. Die Wendung bildete sich deshalb aus, weil noch viele andere Kirchen in Europa behaupteten, die Gebeine des Jakobus zu besitzen, weil sie damit Pilger und deren Spenden anlocken konnten.** "Der Wahre Jacob" war auch eine ab 1879 systemkritische Satirezeitschrift, die 1933 verboten wurde.

[Hier](http://www.wissen.de/apostel-jakobus-der-wahre-jakob) ist eine weitere Quelle:

> Wer aber ist dieser Jakob? Gemeint ist der heilige Jakobus, der Apostel, der 44 n. Chr. in Jerusalem den Märtyrertod erlitt. Nach einer Legende soll er zwei Jahre lang in Spanien das Christentum verkündet haben, nach einer anderen legten seine Jünger den Leichnam ihres Meisters in ein steuerloses Schiff, das in Padrón, unweit des heutigen Santiago de Compostela im Nordwesten Spaniens, an Land trieb. Wie auch immer: Zwischen 812 und 824 wurden dort angeblich die sterblichen Überreste dieses Jüngers Jesu entdeckt. Schon 844 berichtete ein arabischer Reisender von normannischen Pilgern in dieser Gegend, 850 erschienen bereits fromme Friesen in Santiago - Sant Jago bedeutet ja nichts anderes als heiliger Jakob.

Comment: Also _darum_ heisst es auch _Jakobsweg_ und der geht quer durch Europa nach Spanien!

Answer (score 3):

Eine andere Deutung lautet:

> Der Titel leitet sich von einer Redensart ab: Wenn etwas „(nicht) der
>   wahre Jakob“ ist, trifft es genau den Kern der Sache (oder eben
>   nicht). Ursprung dieser Redensart ist die biblische Erzählung von
>   Jakob und Esau. Als Jakob seinen Bruder Esau um Erstgeburtsrecht und
>   Erstgeburtssegen betrügt, sagt Esau zu seinem Vater: „Er heißt mit
>   Recht Jakob“ (= der Hinterlistige). (1 Mos 27,36).

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_wahre_Jacob